# ireport with hibernate, Could not instantiate dialect class

Tags: hibernate, ireport

I am working with hibernate and iReport, configure the classpath well, but I get this error Could not instantiate dialect class, esoty working with SQLServer.

this is the dialect

```
<property name="dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect </property>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs when you have two different versions of hibernate being used in your project and the ireport classpath. Make sure that both your project and ireport classpath points to same version of hibernate.